# start / stop windows service via C# with run as admin without UAC prompt window

Tags: c#, uac

I need to start / stop a windows service from C# code at specific time everyday. So i have written a simple C# program. My program only works when i run it as administrator. Its fine I have written code to run my program as admin.

Now i am stuck in the situation where my C# code runs the `exe` file as "Admin" but the UAC window appears with `program wants to change settings etc` msg.

I need my c# code file runs under windows scheduler which means no human interaction is wanted.  As for UAC window, user needs to select yes.

How can i get rid of that or work around so my program will execute and stop service completely pragmatically without any human interaction?

Answer (score 2):

Create a version of your program that accepts a

```
Sam.exe /StopAndStopTheWindowsServiceINeedToSmack
```

On startup of your app, check for the command line switch. If present, then to the stop/start.

Then create a scheduled task which runs your app with the command line option, and has the **Run with highest privileges** option set:

[image]

Then use the [Task Scheduler 2.0 API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to programatically start the scheduled task.

## Bonus Chatter: A chunk of code

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //Ideally this would be in program.cs, before the call to Application.Run()
    //But that would require me to refactor code out of the Form file, which is overkill for a demo
    if (FindCmdLineSwitch("StopAndStopTheWindowsServiceINeedToSmack", true))
    {
        RestartService("bthserv"); //"Bluetooth Support Service"
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}

private bool FindCmdLineSwitch(string Switch, bool IgnoreCase)
{
    foreach (String s  in System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs())
    {
        if (String.Compare(s, "/" + Switch, IgnoreCase) == 0)
            return true;
        if (String.Compare(s, "-" + Switch, IgnoreCase) == 0)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And we restart the service:

```
private void RestartService(String ServiceName)
{
    TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30000); //30 seconds

    using (ServiceController service = new ServiceController(ServiceName))
    {
        try
        {
            service.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error stopping service");
            return;
        }
        service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);

        try
        {
            service.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error starting service");
            return;
        }
        service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, timeout);
    }
}
```

Bonus: checking if you're running elevated:

```
private Boolean IsUserAnAdmin()
{
    //A user can be a member of the Administrator group, but not an administrator.
    //Conversely, the user can be an administrator and not a member of the administrators group.

    //Check if the current user has administrative privelages
    var identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
    return (null != identity && new WindowsPrincipal(identity).IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator));
}
```

> **Note**: Any code released into public domain. No attribution required.